# Using SUMIFS formula with dynamic range

Tags: excel, formula

I wonder if there is a way I can use the below SUMIFS formula on a dynamic range without having to click on the formula and drag down to capture the whole range manually every time

```
=SUMIFS($I$58:$I$573,$J$58:$J$573,"OK",$F$58:$F$573,C3,$C$58:$C$573,B3)
```

Comment: Is there any reason to not use full-column references: `I:I`, `J:J`, `F:F`, and `C:C`?

Comment: @BigBen SUMIFS is a heavy calculation function.  Using full columns and doing more than a couple thousand really bogs down the calcs.  If I was going to have a column full I would limit the scope to the data range also.

Comment: @ScottCraner I though SUMIFS was optimized for full-column references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-tips-for-optimizing-performance-obstructions#alternatively-use-whole-column-and-row-references. Or is that only SUMIF?

Comment: not really, try it  do 10,000 rows of data then do a sumifs and drag it down the full depth.  If it does not crash your Excel, it will probably return all 0.  Then try the same with the data range only and you will see it works.

Comment: So you're saying the MSFT link is incorrect?

Comment: in my experience yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248603/discussion-between-scott-craner-and-bigben).

Comment: Sorry, chat's blocked by work :-(

Comment: I may have spoken too soon.  The scenario I proposed in older version would crash my excel or return `0`.  With my current version it works fine.  I think I remember reading somewhere that with the advent of the dynamic functions they tweaked how repetitive ranges are stored and used.  but I thought that was only lookups

Comment: So for the OP, Long story short, Most likely the use of full column will not be a detriment and much easier to maintain when using SUMIFS

Comment: that was something :D thanks all. @ScottCraner i tried to use the full column, it worked but for &J&58 it has to start from cell J58 otherwise it will lead to a circular reference in my calculation, What can I do?

Comment: Use `J58:J1040000` and so on.

Comment: If you specify the row, I believe you'll run into that issue you mentioned. However, as ben specified, using the entire column I think got cleaned up to only reference `usedrange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range size is fixed, I suggest that you can use the **SUMIFS** function and wrapped **OFFSET** function inside it.

```
OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

Use the $I$58 as the reference in offset function, and replace the sum_range, criteria_range1, etc. in SUMIFS function.

Next time, just change some numbers in the formula, but you need to do some calculators.

Hope it can be helpful.

Note:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A10,A2,B2:B10)
=SUMIF(OFFSET(A2,0,0,9,1),A2,OFFSET(B2,0,0,9,1))

=SUMIFS(I58:I573,J58:J573,"OK",F58:F573,C3,C58:C573,B3)
=SUMIFS(OFFSET(I58,0,0,516,1),OFFSET(J58,0,0,516,1),"OK",OFFSET(F58,0,0,516,1),C3,OFFSET(C58,0,0,516,1),B3)
```

Comment: `OFFSET` is volatile and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @freemangifts i tried offset but error messages says too many arguments

Comment: I can't think of a situation where `offset` or `indirect` should ever be used. Everything it does could be replicated through a non volatile function such as index or by using a dynamic named range (i.e. no `$`).

Comment: I agree with pgSystemTester to use a dynamic named range.
@Martin, if you want to use OFFSET method, you can try the new formula which I edited. I use it in Excel and it works for me.

Comment: @freemangifts Worked perfectly ! i really appreciate your time solving this.

Comment: Just to be clear, this formula does EXACTLY what your Sumifs/offset option does, while avoiding being a volatile function, which bigBen correctly notes is something to be avoided... : 
 `=SUMIFS($I$58:INDEX($I:$I,573),1),$J$58:INDEX($J:$J,573,1),"OK",$F$58:INDEX($F:$F,573,1),C3,$C$58:INDEX($C:$C,573,1),B3)`

Comment: @pgSystemTester Thank you. I know your method is much more efficient, but sometimes, the good way to solve the problem is not the most efficient method, like "It doesn't matter if a cat is black or white, so long as it can catch mice."Hope it didn't offend you, I personally like offset much more than index.

Comment: It's not offensive at all just demonstrably inefficient. Your cat analogy isn't accurate in that it assumes black and white cats are the same (I presume they are?). A better analogy would be a cat with three legs vs a cat with four legs. Sure the one with three legs can catch some mice, but isn't an optimal candidate for the job of mouse catching compared to the four-legged critter.

Comment: I suspect you aren't familiar with specifically what indirect/volatile functions are since you state you "like offset much more than index" (cringe).  It's not a preference, it's a less optimal choice.  To illustrate, if you put our two calculations next to each other in the same spreadsheet, yours will need to recalculate if an edit is made in column z, or on a *different sheet*, while mine would only calculate on the ranges specified.  That might be harmless for a small dataset, but it will become an issue with larger datasets ESPECIALLY with using Sumifs. You'll change your mind some day 

Comment: OK, you are right. I always handle some small datasets with excel in daily life, so recalculation with OFFSET is not an issue for me, and it is much more understandable, but as you said, if I will work as a data scientist, I do prefer Python and Pandas, not excel... If I have to, I will seriously think index "cat" and appreciate your explanation to learn more about it. 

Comment: See I'm naive about Python and Pandas other than what i've seen at the zoo. I'm probably unaware of the advantages.  In case you're interested, i built [this excel sheet](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=7D665EED73FFBB23!74312&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!APSknV6pegigamo) to illustrate the specific issue of volatile. I may post this somewhere to make it more available as I've had this discussion with a number of people lately. Anyway... good chat. Good luck.

Comment: @Martin, you didn't need to change `accept`. FreeMagnate is new and can use the check.

Comment: @pySystemTester Morning, I am interested in what you are concerned about regarding the volatility, and I like the guys who are persistent in figuring out the principle of the issue. I will check it out and willing to get more understanding of that. Nice talk.

Comment: @pySystemTester Indeed, the speed is totally different. Thank you for the example and letting me learn some more about the volatile function. The following Excel functions are volatile: NOW, TODAY, RANDBETWEEN, OFFSET, INDIRECT, INFO (depending on its arguments), CELL (depending on its arguments), SUMIF (depending on its arguments).

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

I noticed my prior formula (now removed) was performing slower than a volatile function (??) due to the repetitive last row calculation.  The easy solution is to either have a cell explicitly stating the last row, or just use the [LET function](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-much-benefit-does-excels-new-let-function-offer-steven-rider/).

```
=LET(lastRow,MAX(FILTER(ROW(J:J),J:J<>"")),
 SUMIFS( $I$58:INDEX($I:$I,lastRow,1),
         $J$58:INDEX($J:$J,lastRow,1),"OK",
           $F$58:INDEX($F:$F,lastRow,1),C3,
                $C$58:INDEX($C:$C,lastRow,1),B3))
```

I also noticed that the accepted answer simply hard-coded the last row (which to me seems to defeat the whole purpose of this question but I digress). This function does exactly the same thing but isn't a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function). Frankly, this just seems like more work than just using a regular range, but again... I digress...

```
   =SUMIFS($I$58:INDEX($I:$I,573),1),$J$58:INDEX($J:$J,573,1),"OK",
     $F$58:INDEX($F:$F,573,1),C3,$C$58:INDEX($C:$C,573,1),B3)
```

Comment: I tried the above formula but received an error: That function isn't valid

Comment: @Martin you may be on an older version of Excel. If you type `=Filter(` does the formula autopopulate? I updated with a more simplified index answer that does exactly the same as accepted answer but isn't volatile. Glad you got a solution so don't worry about it.

Comment: I tried this and it worked smoothly, of course, it would be better than a volatile function, appreciate your efforts.